# How to create golang web socket chat?

Tags: go, websocket, chat

Good afternoon. 
How to create a golang web socket chat with the ability to send messages to the selected user, and not all?

Comment: Walking the fine line of self promotion here .. but, [my package might help you to get started](https://github.com/simon-whitehead/relayr) .. however I don't currently have a `SendDirectlyToUser` method. You could, however, just assign users to groups and send to the group (the direct send is coming .. I just haven't had time..).

Comment: take the Gorilla websocket example and instead of a broadcast be selective about the user you are sending to. https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/hub.go

Comment: I have used examples from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysAZ_oqPOo0  and Gorilla, but i can not make message direct to user

Comment: Right - well, we aren't going to write code for you. Show us what you have and explain the issues you're having and we can help you understand the problem.

Comment: I have chat from https://github.com/jakecoffman/go-angular-tutorial/tree/master/tutorial_2 and i have function send_to_all.  I want connected and write my id. Client send message {client_id:22,to_id:1,message:'Hello'}  and server send message to user 1 from user 22.     http://prntscr.com/6kj6k3

Answer (score 6):

Refer to this example GO chat application:

```
http://gary.burd.info/go-websocket-chat
```

I tested this out last year and it worked well. You can look at the code to see how it works.

Comment: https://github.com/garyburd/gary.burd.info/tree/master/go-websocket-chat   I can compile, but dont work. Console show 0,5 sekunde and dont work

Comment: @RomanRakzin The project has a `README.md` file, you can follow the instructions on how to build it by using the `README.md`

Answer (score 0):

Another great example is this: https://github.com/arschles/go-in-5-minutes/tree/master/episode4

There is a tutorial video that goes along with this source code:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJiOrGRsIKo